# React Native, Expo 39: Scan barcodes using expo-camera in Web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

Recently, Expo got a nice upgrade to version 39 and they claim you can now scan barcodes in the Browser using expo-camera: https://dev.to/expo/expo-sdk-39-is-now-available-1lm8

It works fine for Android and iOS, but I still can't use it in the Browser (I know I can use other scanning libraries for Web, but it would be great to just use one library `expo-camera`)

Is there any extra configuration?

my `package.json`

```
...
dependencies: {
  ...,
  "expo": "~39.0.2",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
  "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
  "expo-camera": "~9.0.0",
  ...
}
```

`MyCamera.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanningResult, Camera } from 'expo-camera';

function PPCamera() {
  // properties
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  let camera: Camera | null;

  // methods
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
        setHasPermission(true);
      } else {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
        console.log({ status });

        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = (scanResult: BarCodeScanningResult) => {
    console.log({ scanResult });
    const { type, data } = scanResult;
    setScanned(true);
    alert(data);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setScanned(false);
    }, 1000);
  };

  // render
  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    isFocused && (
      <Camera
        ref={(ref) => {
          camera = ref;
        }}
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      />
    )
  );
}

export default PPCamera;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  camera: {
    height: '80%',
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
});
```

The Component works on Web and the camera is showing, but I just don't get any `onBarCodeScanned` event. I have even tried taking pictures and it works in all platforms: `let photo = await camera.takePictureAsync({ base64: true, quality: 0.5 });`

Thank you!

Comment: Any Luck for scanning in web.

Answer (score 0):

In managed apps, Camera requires

### Permissions.CAMERA

Add Permission in App.json file
[image]
Link - https://docs.expo.io/versions/v39.0.0/sdk/permissions/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All works fine for Android or iOS, but only for Web the scanning stops working (the camera turns on, but just doesn't scan). I do have camera permissions in my app.json. `NSCameraUsageDescription` for ios and `"permissions": ["CAMERA"],` for android